# Arrays is not sorting whit sort(); that i get out of an Get request from json that is json.parsed Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

Im trying to get data from an API that send json I succeeded in retrieving the data and all pushing it into 1 array but the problem is that when I sort the array and then `console.log` it its still random for some reason or sometimes it didn't even pull all the data from the API so I'm not getting all the data in the log when it sorts. (that's still random)

script.js

```
"use strict";

const dataLinks = [
  "https://api.data.amsterdam.nl/bbga/cijfers/",
  "https://api.data.amsterdam.nl/bbga/gebieden/",
  "https://api.data.amsterdam.nl/bbga/groepen/",
  "https://api.data.amsterdam.nl/bbga/meta/",
  "https://api.data.amsterdam.nl/bbga/themas/",
  "https://api.data.amsterdam.nl/bbga/variabelen/"
];

const allDataInArray = [];
let ResetNumber = 0;

init();

//Go thruw all links
function init() {
  for (ResetNumber = 0; ResetNumber < dataLinks.length; ResetNumber++) {
    GetAllData(dataLinks[ResetNumber]);
  }
  makeArrays();
}

//Open the links in a get GET request
//then make from the json an Array
//push all into 1 array
function GetAllData(hrefLink) {
  let xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      let myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      // console.log(myObj)
      allDataInArray.push(myObj);
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", hrefLink, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}

function makeArrays() {
  allDataInArray.sort();
  console.log(allDataInArray);

}
```

Comment: Hint: this is a synchronicity problem. Basically you can change your code in a matter to wait to get all the data before sorting it.

Comment: Also that but its also an multidimensional array even if i put timeout on it for llike 5 sec and get all the arrays still is not able to be sorted. @codtex ty for the hint

Comment: Different data structures are coming from the different endpoints. What is actually your desired result, how do you want to sort the data?

Comment: the arrays has 6 object i want to order those object in a way so i can use them in a table better instead of them beeing random return back every time

Answer (score 0):

By default, the sort() method sorts the values as strings in alphabetical and ascending order.
if you want to sort array for an object or number then use it with compare function
`array.sort(compareFunction)`

Comment: Not going to make a difference in this case

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems here.

The first one ist that your return values are `Object`s and you will have to define a custom sort function to pass to `Array.sort` in order to get a correctly sorted result.

Another problem is that you have to wait for all requests to finish before sorting the result array. A standard way to do that is to use `Promise.all` and `fetch` (which wraps a request into a `Promise`).

You can use the following code as a template and fill in a definition of `sortFunction` to make it work altogether.

```
const dataLinks = [
    "https://api.data.amsterdam.nl/bbga/cijfers/",
    "https://api.data.amsterdam.nl/bbga/gebieden/",
    "https://api.data.amsterdam.nl/bbga/groepen/",
    "https://api.data.amsterdam.nl/bbga/meta/",
    "https://api.data.amsterdam.nl/bbga/themas/",
    "https://api.data.amsterdam.nl/bbga/variabelen/"
];

let allDataInArray;

Promise.all(dataLinks.map(link => fetch(link).then(response => { if (response.ok) { return response.json(); }})))
.then(result => { allDataInArray = result.sort(sortFunction); })
```

Note that any code which wants to use `allDataInArray` has to wait as well. You can implement the **observer** pattern for that.